# Менять цвет 4х элементов при скролле(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Задача:

Есть 10 шарика, первые 4 с прозрачностью( 1й - белый, 2 - светло-голубой, 3 - голубой, 4 - синеватый), оставшиеся все синие.
Нужно реализовать плавную смену цвета шариков при скролле, если скроллить вниз - цвета как бы "перебегают" вправо, при сколле вверх  - влево.

Сейчас сделан только каркас.
В одном div'e 2 span объекта - один синий, другой белый. Мысль такая, при скролле добавлять белому span'у разные opacity.

Но как это сделать - понятия не имею.

Спасибо за внимание!

html

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="woman-spine">
    <div class="dot" data-scroll="1">
      <span class="spine-dot"></span>
      <span class="spine-dot-white"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-scroll="2">
      <span class="spine-dot"></span>
      <span class="spine-dot-white"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-scroll="3">
      <span class="spine-dot"></span>
      <span class="spine-dot-white"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-scroll="4">
      <span class="spine-dot"></span>
      <span class="spine-dot-white"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-scroll="5">
      <span class="spine-dot"></span>
      <span class="spine-dot-white"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-scroll="6">
      <span class="spine-dot"></span>
      <span class="spine-dot-white"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-scroll="7">
      <span class="spine-dot"></span>
      <span class="spine-dot-white"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-scroll="8">
      <span class="spine-dot"></span>
      <span class="spine-dot-white"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-scroll="9">
      <span class="spine-dot"></span>
      <span class="spine-dot-white"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="dot" data-scroll="10">
      <span class="spine-dot"></span>
      <span class="spine-dot-white"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body{ height: 1200px; }
.section { padding: 150px 0; }
.woman-spine { position: absolute; top: 87%; left: 24%; width: 50%; }
.dot { 
    position: relative; float: left; margin-right: 3%; 
    width: 15px; height: 15px; 
 }
.spine-dot { 
    position: absolute; width: 15px; height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%; background: #00aeef; 
 }
.spine-dot-white {
    position: absolute; width: 15px; height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%; background: #FFF; opacity: 0; 
 }
```

[Каркас на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tuamdpsg/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основываясь на [английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755887/jquery-change-background-color-user-scroll), написал [пример на базе Вашей заготовки](https://jsfiddle.net/orqbrn7x/7/)

```
//Установка прозрачности для заданного по номеру элемента
function setDotOpacity(dotNumber, opacity) {
    var dotElement = $('div[data-scroll='+dotNumber+'] .spine-dot-white');
    dotElement.css('opacity', opacity);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Шаг по высоте для сдвига цвета
    //12 = 10 + 2, т.к. цвет меняется еще вокруг элемента, 
    //чтобы на первом и последнем не останавливалось на 50% opacity
    var hdot = $(document).height() / (12);

    $( window ).scroll(function() {
        //Расчитываем где центр
        var dotCenter = Math.round($(window).scrollTop() / hdot);

        //Центр делаем полупрозрачным
        setDotOpacity(dotCenter, 0.5);

        //Все что левее центра делаем белым
        for (var i = 0; i < dotCenter; i++) {
            setDotOpacity(i, 1);
        }

        //Все что правее центра делаем синим
        for (var i = dotCenter+1; i <= 10; i++) {
            setDotOpacity(i, 0);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Доброго времени суток, @evgenii-izhboldin!
Все прекрасно работает, но не подскажете, как сделать, чтобы вся эта функция работала только в определенном div'e? Внутри этого блока нет скролла, это обычная секция с заголовком и картинкой и padding'ом в 100px.
Соответственно  $('.my-div').scroll(function() не работает, как заставить работать эту функцию в блоке высотой ~700, и чтобы пока мы скроллим в этих рамках, функция полностью отрабатывала?(т.е чтобы все кружки заполнялись прозрачностью).
За решение отдельное спасибо! Очень выручили!

Comment: @Frunky, как я вижу решение: если скролл глобальный, то листнер `scroll` вешаем так-же на `window`: `$( window ).scroll(function() { ... }`. И работаем от `$('.my-div').offset().top` до `$('.my-div').offset().top + $('.my-div').height()` по тому-же принципу. [Пример здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/o7n16nsb/1/), там только div-second меняет цвета точек

Comment: Это просто гениально! Все почти предельно просто! Спасибо огромное, Женя! Успехов Вам)